# Is banning a user's answering/asking privilege because of a "negative reaction" correct?

Tags: feature-request, post-ban, ban

A negative reaction can easily start on a post with a few mistakes that are usually grammatical mistakes which can lead to confusion, people can downvote the question, then the asker's reputation points decrease. An answer ban may be put on the *user*. Most *downvoter* don't feel the *magnitude* and importance of a downvote and do not take it seriously.

You can't request to have the ban lifted. The asker may lose multiple privileges also.

So I'm proposing that bans because of *"negative reactions"* be banned. What do you think? Do you agree with me? I need the thoughts of other moderators and users.

Comment: You don't need a mod. You should have done some research before posting this. Similar things have been mentioned before, and negatively received. If a user decides to provide low quality contributions to the network the appropriate action is to downvote. So others know its not worth their time reading that answer.

Comment: Voting on any of the Meta sites is different than on the main sites. On Meta sites, votes much more strongly represent people's agreement or disagreement with the position expressed in the post, rather than just an expression of people's opinion on the quality of the post, although they can also reflect that. That you are getting downvotes here is (mostly) people indicating disagreement with the position which you have taken (i.e. people are saying 'banning a user's Answering/Asking privilege because of a "Negative reaction" is correct').

Comment: You're continuing to run into question-bans because you're continuing the same behaviours you've exhibited ever since you started using Stack Exchange: spamming low-quality questions, spamming comments whenever you are downvoted to demand an explanation, deleting posts in response to constructive criticism instead of trying to improve them, and (I suspect) raising frivolous, unneeded flags. **You need to listen to what we are telling you and improve the quality of your contributions, or this is going to keep happening everywhere you go on the network.**

Comment: I'm a moderator on History Stack Exchange, where you are currently question banned. Your question record is...not good. In most cases, it looks like you are asking questions that you already know the answer to in order to seek affirmation of your viewpoints (X sucks, am I right?). This is not how Stack Exchange works at all, which likely explains why your questions were so poorly received. Flag me down in chat sometime and I will help you, if you wish.

Comment: 'can.....'few mistakes'....'usually'....'can'....'can'... :((   Long story, no evidence, no numbers, no nothing.  You are making stuff up, fake news to support your POV.   You can prove me wrong with evidence.........

Comment: History SE gets a *lot* of "Did X country really commit Y atrocity?" questions. In most cases, the answer is "Yes, they did". If you did some research and are interested in more details, then sure, post a question. If you just want others to commiserate with you over how evil X must be, then please find a more appropriate venue.

Comment: @RobertColumbia i wish i could have my question ban lifted but i dont know how they lif that

Comment: You posted five comments on this question in the space of five minutes, demanding an explanation for the downvotes and for moderators to get involved. I'm sorry, but to me, that's spam.

Comment: If you're going to interpret my (harsh but constructive) feedback as "rude" and "a mob... throwing me under the bus", then there's no point in me replying to you any further. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Lawyer it looks like your question ban on History.SE is no longer in effect. Please be careful before asking another question. If in doubt, please seek help in chat or on the site's meta. You need good questions to keep yourself from getting question banned again. If you don't know what to ask, or just want to post because you think you ought to be more active, please refrain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure which site you have a post-ban on but looking across all the sites you use there do seem to be many answers with negative scores so it is not just a problem you have with the users of one site but with nearly all of them. It might be a good idea to take any site on which you are not banned and ask on the child meta there for advice about why your posts receive such feedback. They will know the customs and practices of their site. Then perhaps you can work on editing and improving your posts there and gradually restore your privileges. Note that nobody can do anything about this for you, the bans are automated.

Comment: That the user is banned from posting answers, or even questions, on a main site doesn't mean they are banned from posting questions on the site's meta. Thus, they could post a question on the Meta site for the site where they are experiencing the answer ban. In fact, it's probably more appropriate for them to post on the Meta for the site where they are experiencing the problem. They might also get good advice on other Meta sites where they are also seeing negative reactions, but it won't be specific to the site where they are actually having the problem.

Comment: You may be conflating the question and answer bans (automatically imposed by the system) with suspension from the site (imposed by moderators). A suspension would prevent the user from posting on the site's meta, but the question and answer bans are actually separate for the site and the site's Meta. The question and answer bans are, usually, significantly harder to receive on the Meta sites, and may be completely disabled on some site's Metas.

Comment: @Makyen I thought the OP might be better to practice on a site where they were in better standing first before they started on the tricky ones. Perhaps I should have made that clearer. I did in fact know the rule you mention as I have seen it in operation on one of the sites I use but thanks for pointing it out for the benefit of the OP.